# SQL - Copying fields up in table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table which will vary in size(i.e. number of columns) but the last column contains a piece of information which I want to be "copied up" to all rows above.

I want to create a query which turns the below table...

```
    ID  Cust_Number
    1   aaa
    2   aaa
    3   aaa
    4   aaa
    5   aaa
    6   aaa
    7   aaa
    8   aaa
    9   aaa
    10  bbb
```

to turn into this:

```
    ID  Cust_Number
    1   bbb
    2   bbb
    3   bbb
    4   bbb
    5   bbb
    6   bbb
    7   bbb
    8   bbb
    9   bbb
    10  bbb
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
UPDATE YourTable t
SET T.CustNumber = (SELECT TOP 1 s.Cust_Number FROM YourTable s
                    ORDER BY s.ID DESC)
```

Comment: Thanks Sagi,Unfortunatly this didn't work I received the below error:

"Operation must use an updateable query."